# Handling stdin and stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, pipe

I'm trying to use `subprocess` to handle streams. I need to write data to the stream, and be able to read from it **asynchronously** (before the program dies, because mine's will take minutes to complete, however it products output).

For the learn case, I've been using the `timeout` command from Windows 7:

```
import subprocess
import time

args = ['timeout', '5']
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
p.stdin.write('\n') # this is supposed to mimic Enter button pressed event.

while True:
    print p.stdout.read() # expected this to print output interactively. This actually hungs.
    time.sleep(1)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
print p.stdout.read() # expected this to print output interactively. This actually hungs.
```

hangs because `read()` means "read all data until EOF". See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html). It seems like you may have wanted to read a line at a time:

```
print p.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: It reads the data until EOF of the buffer. It won't hung if the buffer gets empty.

Comment: @iTayb No, it waits until end-of-file. For a pipe end-of-file is when the input-producing process closes the file or terminates. EOF does not occur simply because a process temporarily stops writing. Try e.g. running `python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.read()"` and see whether that mirrors only the first line you write or every line you write once you have indicated EOF with Ctrl-Z/Ctrl-D/similar.